# Using JSON.NET or really anything to search for a value in JSON and the return another value of the same object?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Hopefully the title makes sense, but I can't figure out how to do this.

For context, I'm using the Unity game engine ( C# ), and I'm basically making a Twitch stream chat overlay type thing, and I'm trying to add functionality with BTTV emotes.

I have this long JSON list from the BTTV api of emotes and their ID's which I need to get the image. The way I plan on doing it is having it so when someone in chat sends the BTTV emote (which is read as text by the system), it will search and find a matching value in the JSON and return the id of the same object. The actual list is much longer, and has actual names instead of just "Object" but this is how I'm doing this as my example.

I don't know what the name will be beforehand, so I need to do it all through code. I just don't know how and can't seem to figure out how.

In a nutshell, I need to input the text in yellow and have it return the text in green.

[image]

Comment: Create a class that has properties `Id`, `Code`, and `ImageType`, serialize to a list of that class, and then use LINQ (or manually iterate through) to find the element with the code you want to find, and then return the Id.

Comment: do you mean you want to change the color of json values or you want the id of matching code. ? Share the JSON as text.

Comment: I want the id of the matching code.
JSON text: https://pastebin.com/WhEWj70y